# In Batman Beyond episode Rebirth Part 2, did Bruce take a copy of the disc?

Tags: dc, batman, dc-animated-universe, batman-beyond

In the episode [Rebirth Path 2](https://dcau.fandom.com/wiki/Rebirth) of Batman Beyond, after inspecting the disc on Bruce's computer, are we to believe that Bruce didn't take a copy of the disc before giving it back to Terry? Seems like an incredibly stupid thing to forget, if that disc contains the only evidence they have... And of course the disc was stolen by Derek before Terry got to the police station.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that. I'm going to edit that back into disc then.

Comment: @Clockwork i didn't know it either until looking it up because of your edit ^^

Comment: Its modern technology, Bruce probably had only Read rights but not copy or delete rights on that disc.

Comment: @jo1storm guess [DRM technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management) of the future is so advanced that even Batman can't break it :P

Comment: We are lucky he was able to play it at all on that old piece of supercomputer. I guess Bruce remained tech enthusiast even after retiring as Batman. He always wanted to have the shiniest toys in the neighborhood.